# people picker not resolving names correctly

Tags: user-profile, active-directory, people-picker

We have our sharepoint server in a domain named DMZ. Our AD users are in another domain, say domain ACME. In the DMZ domain we also have external SP users. All of a sudden the people picker will resolve the DMZ names properly but not the ACME names.

If I open the people picker user search, only DMZ users show up. I have also verified there is still trust between the servers/domains

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem on a specific application? See http://habaneroconsulting.com/insights/Trusted-domain-users-not-resolving-in-Central-Admin-People-Picker#.U9kgOPldUQd

Is a separate account used for searching for users? Check using stsadm.exe -o setproperty -url http://yourapp.com -pn "peoplepicker-searchadforests" See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd279546(v=office.14).aspx

Is there anything useful in the trace logs? I've seen people picker errors logged in the trace log before, but you might have to configure verbose logging.

Did a firewall change? http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2009/01/21/people-picker-port-protocol-requirements.aspx

Comment: The only thing I see in the event vwr is this, right around the time I ran the incremental sync: The management agent "MOSS-9f8a847e-cecb-4a18-8b16-f94901952bee" completed run profile "MOSS_DELTASYNC_58b4b501-b81c-44ca-b1c2-f89bb7802369" with a delta import or delta synchronization step type. The rules configuration has changed since the last full synchronization.
 
 User Action
 To ensure the updated rules are applied to all objects, a run with step type of full synchronization should be completed

Comment: That has to do with the FIM service, which I know has something to do with UPS. I don't know if that would cause the issue with the domain user not showing up. They are all in SP user profile manager. I ran stsadm -o getproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests and it returned <Property Exist="No" />

Comment: Try setting the trace logging to verbose temporarily. Then try resolving a user in the people picker in a site which you know it was working previously. Immediately after you try the people picker, open the latest trace log and start doing a search for the name you were entering into the people picker. SharePoint 2013 will query AD every time a character is enter so you might have to search for "jsm" if you typed jsmith into the people picker.

Comment: The FIM Service performs the User Profile Sync for the User Profile Service (UPS). It's unrelated in this case. The User Profile Service isn't needed for the People Picker to resolve names (UPS is an enterprise only feature and SP Foundation supports resolving names in the People Picker). What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: We are on SP 2010

Comment: I test my name and it says "No exact match was found" even though the correctly resolved name shows up in the box. I checked the logs with verbose enabled and there is nothing. One thing I noticed is if I click the check names icon twice, it resolves. I think I need to bounce the server...

Comment: Rebooting the farm is certainly a valid troubleshooting step at this point. We don't have much to go after at this point.

Comment: It turns out there was an upgrade performed on our active directory which involved removing a DNS server. I am not 100% sure either of these were the cause, but it was about the same time we started having the problem with the people picker. The next day, the people picker started working again.